# "Pie chart"-like data point for scatter diagram in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, pie-chart, datapoint

I got to the stage in data analysis, where I need to show multiple dimensions in a single plot in order to better emphasize correlations. Placing a pie-chart for every data point would be the best way to go. Appended here a figure I found at: https://andypope.info/charts/piedatamarkers.htm

How can I produce such a graph in Gnuplot 5.2? I know it is not possible by standard plot types, I am looking for a workaround. I would go along loops and using Python to make a script that generates such a plot.

[image]

Comment: How does your data look like? Have you checked this http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/circles.html  The example there should also work in gnuplot 5.2

Comment: I don't have a fixed data structure, it is flexible. For the time being, I preprocess the data with Python to list the positions, radii, angles and colors of the circles in six columns. It is far from ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly simplified variation of the example mentioned [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/circles.html), especially the plot command is shorter and clearer.

The radius of the pie-charts are either fixed: value>0 in column3 or or automatic: value<0 in column3. In the latter case, the area of the circle is proportional to the total sum of the columns.
The arc colors can be chosen as `0xRRGGBB` colors. This example may serve as a starting point for further improvements and adaptions.

**Code:**

```
### plot with piecharts as points
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# x y    r  c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
2   16  -1  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5  3.0
3    5  -1  0.8  0.7  0.5  0.9  0.8
7   15  -1  1.5  1.3  1.4  2.1  1.2
11  10  -1  5.6  8.7  3.1  3.1  9.4
12  19  -1  1.7  2.5  3.3  1.0  0.9
17   3  -1  4.1  5.1  1.4  0.5  5.3
19  14  -1  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5
22  17  -1  2.1  2.2  3.2  4.2  1.5
EOD

stats $Data nooutput    # get the number of columns
colMax = STATS_columns
colMin = 4              # starting column for data
Scale = 0.3             # general scaling of circles
set angle degrees

Part(i) = sum [col=colMin:i] column(col)
Total(n) = Part(colMax)
Radius(r) = Scale * (r<0 ? sqrt(Total(0)) : r)    # radius<0: automatic calculation, proportional to sqrt
ArcStart = 90                                     # pie-chart start angle: 90=twelve o'clock
ArcDir = -1                                       # direction: -1 = clockwise, 1 = counterclockwise
ArcFrom(i) = ArcDir*Part(int(i)+(ArcDir<0?0:-1))/Total(0)*360 + ArcStart
ArcTo(i)   = ArcDir*Part(int(i)+(ArcDir<0?-1:0))/Total(0)*360 + ArcStart
ArcColor(i) = int(word("0xff0000 0x00ff00 0x0000ff 0xff00ff 0xffff00",i-colMin+1))

set xrange[0:25]
set yrange[0:25]
set grid xtics, ytics
set style fill solid 0.5 noborder

plot for [j=colMin:colMax] $Data u 1:2:(Radius($3)):(ArcFrom(j)):(ArcTo(j)):(ArcColor(j)) w circle lc rgb var notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @theozh! That is a very neat solution! Exactly what I wanted to achieve and could not get done with two or three nested loops. I think your solution should be a textbook example!